# Why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n) \overline{b(n)} n^2$ absolutely converges?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $E = \{a : \mathbb{N}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a(n)|^2 n^2 < \infty \}$.

I don't understand why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n) \overline{b(n)} n^2$ absolutely converges if $a$, $b \in E$. Someone could help me ?

Comment: Duo you know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre One would have to prove that $\langle b_n, a_n\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n) \overline{b(n)} n^2$ is indeed an inner product first, but that doesn't seem too hard. Or is it that this problem is part of showing that this inner product is well-defined? In that case, the CS inequality is circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each complex numbers $x$ and $y$, $2\left|xy\right| \leqslant \left|x\right|^2+\left|y\right| ^2$, hence with $x=a\left(n\right)n$ and $y=b\left(n\right)n$, we get 
$$\left|a\left(n\right)b\left(n\right)n^2\right|\leqslant\frac 12\left|a\left(n\right)\right|^2n^2+\frac 12\left|b\left(n\right)\right|^2n^2.$$